# Need video to mute/unmute on keypress (No Button)

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I'm making an intro video for this game I play and I have music playing in the video that I want people to be able to mute/unmute when pressing spacebar; No idea if I'm going it right I essentially reached this point from pulling various other bits of code together from elsewhere. It doesn't work at all, please help.

Please note: this is not the entire HTML File, I can provide it if necessary. It just has progress bars and stuff in.

this is my code so far:

```html
<video class="introVideo" id="introVideo" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay muted>
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   <script>
       var myVideo = document.getElementById("introVideo");

      function onKeyDown(event) {
             switch (event.keyCode) {
                 case 32: //SpaceBar                    
                     if (muted) {
                         myVideo.muted = true();
                         muted = false;
                     } else {
                         myVideo.muted = false();
                         muted = true;
                     }
                     break;
             }
       return false;
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Just realised you can't even see the video because it's a local source, this is my video here, if you can make it with with an "youtube iframe" embed, i'm more than happy with that. So long as I can still set pointer-events: none.

Youtube Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2x18zIJb-YY

Comment: `myVideo.muted = true();` is incorrect, it should be `myVideo.muted = true;`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I changed that but it's still not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It seems that the variable `muted` is not initialised.
- There is no such thing as `true()` and `false()`
- Your function does not bound to some event. So you should either bind it to some element (with `addEventListener`) or to bind with the old approach of using `ELEMENT.onXXX`
- In order for `document.getElementById` to always work, you better wait for the `document` `ready` event (better to use with jQuery) or the bit later, `window.onload` event.

So the modifications above, plus a bit simpler logic can be written as:

```
<video class="introVideo" id="introVideo" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay muted>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("introVideo");

  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 32: //SpaceBar
        myVideo.muted = !myVideo.muted;
      break;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for a local mp4 file, but i'm having issues loading that mp4 into the client i'm using. Is there any way I can adapt this to a youtube embed using iframe id instead of video?

Comment: ```<iframe class="myVideo" id="myVideo" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2x18zIJb-YY?autoplay=1&mute=1&%3Fvq=hd1080&;controls=0;&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen="";></iframe>
</video>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");

  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 32: //SpaceBar
        myVideo.muted = !myVideo.muted;
      break;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
</script>```

sorry, not sure how formatting works

Comment: Youtube is controlled by a different api. Please refer to the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).
Once you get your video working, and not sure how to bind the events and/or control the `player`, you may ask another question, and the community will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just miss one part, link your keyDown function to user action. You ca ndo it like this:

```
myVideo.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
```

You can add this code just before "< /script>" tag close.
Here is documentation for addEventListener => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Edit: You will probably need also focus your video tag by default, otherwise it will not work. But if you want whole you page interact to mute/unmute do

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
```

Comment: Hm, I thought I already tried this. So I've removed the end brackets from "myVideo.muted = true() and myVideo.muted = false()" like the person above suggested and i've added 

"document.body.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);" just before </script> but it's still not working :S

Comment: As said in previous comment it's probably you have other javascript error in your code.

Comment: Debugging tips, use devtools you can right click on the page and inspect or F12, and then go to "console" tab which will display your errors